# Página não imprimindo os resultados

Tags: php

Estou criando uma tabela com uma célula na forma de input text para entrar um numero, e o restante das células serão imprimidas depois de realizadas as operações para determinar seu valor.

Depois da tabela tem um botão submit para enviar o valor do input text para a variável que dará inicío aos cálculos.

Acontece que não estou conseguindo imprimir os resultados.

```
<form method="POST" action="meixautonomo.php">
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td class="indicador">Informações Gerais</td>
        <td class="indicador">Autonômo</td>
        <td class="indicador">MEI/ME</td>
        <td class="indicador">% de Econômia</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Bônus Bruto</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="entrada"></td>
        <?php
            if(isset($_POST['calcular'])){
                $autonomoBonusBruto = $_POST['entrada'];
                $meimeBonusBruto = $autonomoBonusBruto;
                $porcEconomiaBonusBruto = ($autonomoBonusBruto - $meimeBonusBruto) / $autonomoBonusBruto;
                $autonomoTaxa = 3;
                $meimeTaxa = 3.99;
                $porcEconomiaTaxa = ($autonomoTaxa - $meimeTaxa) / $autonomoTaxa;
                $autonomoINSS;
                if($autonomoTaxa + $meimeTaxa > 5189.82){
                    $autonomoINSS = 570.88;
                }
                else{
                    $autonomoINSS = ($autonomoBonusBruto - $autonomoTaxa) * 0.11;
                }
                $meimeINSS;
                if($meimeBonusBruto <= 5000){
                    $meimeINSS = 44;
                }
                else if($meimeBonusBruto > 5189.82){
                    $meimeINSS = 570.88; 
                }
                else{
                    $meimeINSS = $meimeBonusBruto * 0.11;
                }
                $porcEconomiaINSS = ($autonomoINSS - $meimeINSS) / $autonomoINSS;
                $autonomoIRRF = 2864.91 * 0.15 - 354.80;
                $meimeIRRF;
                if($meimeBonusBruto <= 5000){
                    $meimeIRRF = 21033.22 * 0 - 0 / 12;
                }
                else{
                    $meimeIRRF = $meimeBonusBruto * 0.06;
                }
                $porcEconomiaIRRF = ($autonomoIRRF - $meimeIRRF) / $autonomoIRRF;
                $autonomoISS = $autonomoBonusBruto * 0.05;
                $meimeISS;
                if($meimeBonusBruto <= 5000){
                    $meimeISS = 5; 
                }
                else{
                    $meimeISS = $meimeBonusBruto * 0.05;
                }
                $porcEconomiaISS = ($autonomoISS - $meimeISS) / $autonomoISS;
                $autonomoBonusLiquido = $autonomoBonusBruto - $autonomoTaxa - $autonomoINSS - $autonomoIRRF - $autonomoISS;
                $meimeBonusLiquido = $meimeBonusBruto - $meimeTaxa - $meimeINSS - $meimeIRRF - $meimeISS;
                $porcEconomiaBonusLiquido = ($autonomoBonusLiquido - $meimeBonusLiquido) / $autonomoBonusLiquido;
                $meimeLucro = $meimeBonusLiquido - $autonomoBonusLiquido;
        ?>          
        <td><?php echo $meimeBonusBruto;?></td>
        <td><?php echo $porcEconomiaBonusBruto;?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Taxa DOC/Boleto</td>
        <td><?php echo $autonomoTaxa;?></td>
        <td><?php echo $meimeTaxa;?></td>
        <td><?php echo $porcEconomiaTaxa;?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>INSS</td>
        <td><?php echo $autonomoINSS;?></td>
        <td><?php echo $meimeINSS;?></td>
        <td><?php echo $porcEconomiaINSS;?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>IRRF</td>
        <td><?php echo $autonomoIRRF;?></td>
        <td><?php echo $meimeIRRF;?></td>
        <td><?php echo $porcEconomiaIRRF;?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>ISS</td>
        <td><?php echo $autonomoISS;?></td>
        <td><?php echo $meimeISS;?></td>
        <td><?php echo $porcEconomiaISS;?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Bônus Líquido</td>
        <td><?php echo $autonomoBonusLiquido;?></td>
        <td><?php echo $meimeBonusLiquido;?></td>
        <td><?php echo $porcEconomiaBonusLiquido;?></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<?php echo $meimeLucro;}?>
<br>
<input type="submit" name="calcular" value="Gerar resultados">
</form>
```

Comment: Aparece algum erro ?

Answer (score 2):

Não está muito claro o que pergunta, mas a princípio, olhando superficialmente percebe-se erros básicos.

Abaixo, citarei os mais visíveis. Mas não quer dizer necessariamente que sejam a causa do problema, no entanto, suspeito que ao menos 1 ou 2 desses erros estejam causando o problema. Por isso, recomendo que corrija-os

## PHP: Aspas simples para imprimir variáveis

Exemplo:

```
<?php echo '$porcEconomiaBonusBruto';?>
<?php echo '$meimeBonusBruto';?>
```

Isso imprimirá de forma literal devido as single quotes. Será escrito literalmente:

```
$porcEconomiaBonusBruto
$meimeBonusBruto
```

Uma variável não necessita ser delimitada por aspas.

Corrija dessa forma:

```
<?php echo $porcEconomiaBonusBruto;?>
<?php echo $meimeBonusBruto;?>
```

## HTML: Espaços em atribuidores de atributos e marcação XML

Exemplo:

```
<input type = "submit" name = "calcular" value = "Gerar resultados"/>
```

Não precisa ter espaços nos atribuidores. Correção:

```
<input type="submit" name="calcular" value="Gerar resultados">
```

A barra no final também removi. Isso você usa se o DTD for XHTML.

## HTML: Erro de sintaxe (tag table)

Um problema que pode ser grave é a falta do caracter de fechamento da tag `<table`

```
<table border = "1"
    <tr>
```

Falta o `>` para fechar. Correção:

```
<table border="1">
    <tr>
```

Talvez isso aí que esteja impedindo de ver os resultados. Mas se você pressionar CTRL+U (chrome), poderá ver os códigos.

## HTML: O form está sem action

```
<form method = "POST">
```

Exemplo de como deveria ser:

```
<form method="POST" action="pagina.php">
```

Aí nesse local onde está "pagina.php", obviamente é um EXEMPLO. Você deve colocar a página que receberá os dados.

## Outros

Apenas observação, o trecho em PHP com essa montanha da variáveis nulas, não faz sentido algum.

Também não faz o muito sentido a expressão que `$porcEconomiaBonusBruto` recebe pois sempre resulta em ZERO.

Basicamente, o que está fazendo é atribuir `$_POST['entrada']` para uma variável `$autonomoBonusBruto` que é usada para atribuir valor a outra variável `$meimeBonusBruto`. Por fim,

```
$porcEconomiaBonusBruto = ($autonomoBonusBruto - $meimeBonusBruto) / $autonomoBonusBruto;
```

É o mesmo que fazer `($_POST['entrada'] - $_POST['entrada']) / $_POST['entrada']`.

Não sei o que pretende com isso, por isso me abstenho a prolongar esse assunto, mas achei pertinente comentar.

Comment: Corrigi tudo que você disse mas ainda não deu, o action da um refresh na página, isso acaba fazendo com que o valor das variáveis volte a nulo, não ?

Comment: Não. Quando deixa sem o action é postado para a própria página. Se não mostrou o cálculo, está ainda a fazer algo errado. Basta remover as aspas das variávels  `$meimeBonusBruto` e `$porcEconomiaBonusBruto` conforme comentado na resposta.

Comment: já removi faz tempo a aspas vou editar pra você ver como está o código agora, mais completo.

Comment: e é pra ser exibido os dados na própria página mesmo

Answer (score 2):

Leia os comentários ao lado das variáveis.

Se não existir action o formulário é submetido para a mesma página.

```
<form method = "POST">
<table border = "1">
    <tr>
        <td class = "indicador">Informações Gerais</td>
        <td class = "indicador">Autonômo</td>
        <td class = "indicador">MEI/ME</td>
        <td class = "indicador">% de Econômia</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Bônus Bruto</td>
        <td><input type = "text" name = "entrada" id="entrada" /></td>
        <?php 
        if(isset($_POST['calcular']))
        {
            $autonomoBonusBruto = $_POST['entrada'];
            $autonomoTaxa = 3;
            $autonomoINSS    =1;      // VARIÁVEL = NULL SE NÃO TIVER VALOR DEFINIDO, divisão por zero não existe
            $autonomoIRRF;           // variável não sendo utilizada
            $autonomoISS;               // variável não sendo utilizada
            $autonomoBonusLiquido;  // variável não sendo utilizada
            $meimeBonusBruto = $autonomoBonusBruto;
            $meimeTaxa = 3.99;
            $meimeINSS    =0;            // VARIÁVEL = NULL SE NÃO TIVER VALOR DEFINIDO
            $meimeIRRF;                // variável não sendo utilizada
            $meimeISS;                // variável não sendo utilizada
            $meimeBonusLiquido;        // variável não sendo utilizada

            $porcEconomiaBonusBruto = ($autonomoBonusBruto - $meimeBonusBruto) / $autonomoBonusBruto;
            $porcEconomiaTaxa = ($autonomoTaxa - $meimeTaxa) / $autonomoTaxa;
            $porcEconomiaINSS = ($autonomoINSS - $meimeINSS) / $autonomoINSS;
            $porcEconomiaIRRF;     // variável não sendo utilizada
            $porcEconomiaISS;     // variável não sendo utilizada
            $porcEconomiaBonusLiquido;     // variável não sendo utilizada

            echo '<td>'.$meimeBonusBruto.'</td>';
            echo '<td>'.$porcEconomiaBonusBruto.'</td>';
        }
        else
        {
            echo '<td></td>
                  <td></td>';
        }
        ?>          

    </tr>
</table>
<br/>
<input type = "submit" name = "calcular" value = "Gerar resultados"/>
</form>


<script>
window.onload=function(){ document.getElementById('entrada').focus(); }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

- Atribua valores para as variáveis `$autonomoINSS` e `$meimeINSS` pois
  o cálculo não pode ser feito com valores nulos.
- Retire as aspas ao imprimir os valores das variáveis.